# How to add php tags inside attribute value?

Tags: php, html, string, double-quotes

I'm trying to write meta keywords dynamically with php, so I have such a code , running in WAMP Server localhost/myfile.php :

```
<meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2,
<?php
echo $my_array['index_of_keyword3']; 
?>
">
```

well of course it results in this:

```
 <meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2,<?php echo $my_array['index_of_keyword3']; ?> ">
```

So what should I do to get

```
 <meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2,keyword3 ">
```

?

Thanks !

By the way, I know I could do this with something like

```
<?php echo "<meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"keyword1, keyword2,$myVariable\">"; ?>
```

But I would like to simplify my code, by using php only for the variables.

Edit:
omg, I solved the problem by seeing that I'm an idiot :)

I have wrote `<?php$row=blabla..?>`
changing it to `<?php $row=blabla..?>` solved the issue.
Thanks for all the answers. I will upvote them all.

Comment: are you sure $my_array['index_of_keyword3'] is set?

Comment: Your code should work. Are you sure this is a php file, and it's getting parsed by the server?

Comment: @John yes. I am using WAMPServer, I don't think there is a problem with WAMP.

Comment: Did you try a simple `<?php echo "Hello World!"; ?>` - Did you try the extenstion .php5 instead of .php? Is the address http:// or file:///??

Comment: edit your question to precise you're calling it right ;)

Comment: @martinqt I didn't understand what you are saying :)

Comment: Edit your question to say that your using `localhost/file.php` because that's the most common problem (as you've probably noticed^^)

Comment: ok, I'm adding that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you don't parse the file. How do you call this file because PHP doesn't seem to interpret it?

**EDIT**: In your wamp config try to disable `short open tag`

Comment: I directly open "localhost/thisfile.php" in my browser.
But I guess this is what PHP should do. It recognizes "<?php.. blabla" as a string. IF I would have done content=<?php echo "\"keyword1,etc\"";?> than it would interpret correctly, I guess. But what is the right way to do it inside double quotes?

Comment: won't work. You need a server like apache to ask php to run your file. CConsider using WAMP(windows), XAMP(Mac), LAMP(Linux)

Comment: I am using WAMP's localhost :)

Comment: So you need to type in your browser url `localhost/` followed by the relative path to your wamp `www/` dir. For instance if your script is in the `www/` and named test type `localhost/test.php`

Comment: for debug purpose, run this file in your command line with `php somepage.php` and tell us what happen

Answer (score 2):

I assume your page extention is **.html** and NOT **.php**

Change somepage.html to somepage.php and it should start working.

Comment: Might be something to do with your server setup then.

Comment: Try going through http://binfalse.de/2011/02/apache-not-parsing-php-files/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305680/apache-virtual-host-not-parsing-php

Comment: So are you sure php SHOULD recognize <?php?> tags inside double quotes?

Comment: As long as the tags aren't wrapped around an echo/print statement then -yes.

Comment: I mean make sure there isn't something like:
<?php echo '
<meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2,
<?php
echo $my_array['index_of_keyword3']; 
?>
">';

Comment: No, this part is outside the php tags (inside the html part of my .php file)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo implode(",", $my_array);?>">
```

This way you can print all array content separated with commas. Also make sure your file extension is **.php** to have your code interpreted.

Comment: @CooPer If the problem was the file extension it would be the answer. Also I was trying to show a better way to do what he wants to do.

Comment: +1 as this answer does not deserve negative rating. It "could" be a possible answer even if it's not "the" answer

Comment: @Onimusha i think it cant be answer, question about why php code not execute , not fix this code !

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it has the exact same "problem" with my code: php tags inside double quotes. And I think that is wrong, and I'm seeking for a better way for it. Yet everybody is saying that it should work. Confused :/

Comment: @marvin it is not wrong , php work every where you open <?php tag

Comment: @marvin Reading your comments I see that you are not making a common mistake. Probably it is a problem with your apache config, did you modified it recently?

Comment: @letiagoalves I recently formatted my computer and installed WAMP but I have wrote a lot of php files since, and none did yield a "strange" error like that. But as I am saying, I was expecting this error. So I don't know what to do now :)

Comment: @marvin I am afraid I can't help you. However let me say to you that I use [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/) a long time and never had a problem. If you don't mind leave your current environment, this can _"solve"_ your problem. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Either your file doesn't have a `.php` extension or you're trying to open it directly from filesystem. For PHP to work you need a server, for example [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) for Windows of LAMP package for Linux.

When you have a server running, there will be a directory called `htdocs` in the server's directory. Put your files in there and type `http://localhost/YourFilenameHere` in your browser's address bar to access your files.