# PHP Written out to screen when using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having issues trying to insert information into the database. When I run the database connection in a different file it works fine on its own. But when I do the `->prepare` it writes the PHP, starting from that point, out to the screen. Then I moved my PDO connection to the **register.php** file. That didn't help either. The only thing that changed is that now it writes out the PHP to screen from `->setAttribute` onwards.

Here is the PHP code I use in **register.php**:

```
<?php
//include '../database_connect/connect.php';
PDO::getAvailableDrivers();
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=local_db', 'root', '');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$dob =  $_POST['dob']; 
//$_POST['day'] . $_POST['month'] . $_POST['year'];
//$final_dob = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($dob));


try {
    $sql_query = 'INSERT INTO user_data (username, password, email, first_name, last_name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)';
    $query = $db->prepare($sql_query);
} catch (PDOException $e)
    echo $e->getMessage();
?>
```

This is what I used in the commented **connect.php** and it didn't write PHP out to the browser.

```
<?php
// Get available driver, check if it's installed
//print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=local_db', 'root', '');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

/*try {
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} */
?>
```

I know that the password is not hashed, but this problem hit me before starting to work that out.

Comment: It sounds like your webserver isn't configured correctly, so it's not running `register.php` as a PHP script, it's just treating it as HTML. So `->` is ending the `<?php` tag.

Comment: I am running XAMPP, but the thing I do not understand is then why is the connect.php running without any trouble? And I also have a query that grabs information from the database and outputs it to the browser. Those are working fine, but this is not. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Are they in the same directory? If not, maybe there's a `.htaccess` file in the  directory of `register.php` that's affecting it differently from `connect.php`.

Comment: I moved the files to a different folder, still the same problem. Now the other files are getting PHP written out to the browser as well. And I couldn't find a .htaccess file in the folders.

Comment: It's definitely something wrong with your server configuration. Unfortunately, that's not my area of expertise, which is programming, not server config.

Comment: Are you sure your files have `.php` extensions and not `.php.txt` , because it happened to me once long ago, where I being silly upload a `.php.txt` file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305680/apache-virtual-host-not-parsing-php might help you debugging.

Comment: @Nepal12 Yes, I double checked and all the files are .php extension.

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem. I don't know the reason, but when I pressed the submit button in my index.php, it redirected me to `E://{file_path}` and not `localhost/{file_path}`. Now it is running okay. Thanks for everybody's help.