# AWS Linux Instance PHP is not being parsed when running from my vhosts

Tags: php, linux, apache, amazon-web-services, vhosts

I have set 3 virtual hosts on an AWS Linux AMI instance, HTML files are working file but the PHP files are outputting plain text.
Before I set up the vhosts I tested the PHP files and they were running fine.

I followed these instructions to install the LAMP stack on my instance:
[AWS Install LAMP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html)

I have put the vhosts in the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file, and they look something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain1
<Directory /var/www/html/domain1>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain2
<Directory /var/www/html/domain2>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain3.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain3
<Directory /var/www/html/domain3>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried adding this to httpd.conf

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

but this makes turns the plain text PHP files into downloadable PHP files

Have I been missing something obvious all along?

Comment: restarted apache ? In apache, do you LoadModule php ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried restarting apache

Comment: I tried adding LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so but it returns an error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Virtual Host not parsing PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305680/apache-virtual-host-not-parsing-php)

Comment: Are you going to have us guess at the error you got from `LoadModule`?

Comment: I just tried with LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp-7.0.so which seems to be loading, restarted apache and the php file is still not being parsed

Comment: I just managed to get it working by adding the following to `httpd.conf`:
`LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp-7.0.so
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler php7-script .php`